# Apache solr not listening on 8983 on macos catalina

Tags: ubuntu, solr

Accessing the [link](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/8.8.2/solr-8.8.2.tgz) I am trying to use apache solr on macos catalina.
The folder is in my root directory, but when I run bin/solr start, I see the following:

```
➜  solr-7.7.3 bin/solr start
*** [WARN] *** Your open file limit is currently 256.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 2784.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 180 seconds!
tail: /Users/sidney/solr-7.7.3/server/logs/solr.log: No such file or directory
```

How do I actually run the solr on my local on my mac?

Comment: Start by checking if any of the logs show anything meaningful. You can also give the `-f` argument when starting Solr to make it start in the foreground - any logs should be shown directly in your terminal in that case.

Comment: @MatsLindh I gor an error related to VM "Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit"

Comment: You're using a JVM where the argument `UseConcMarkSweepGC` has been removed. The easiest thing is to instead start with the most recent version of Solr instead of an older one, but if you want to explicitly use 7.7, you should be able to set SOLR_OPTS (if that's the correct name, I don't have a 7.7 install available) in your environment (`export SOLR_OPTS=..`) - but grep (`grep -r UseConcMarkSweepGC`) for the setting in the init scripts and override it through an environment variable or remove it manually from the init scripts.

Comment: Your link points to `solr-8.8.2` but it seems that you are using `solr-7.7.3`. I would do as MatsLindg suggested and use the latest (8.x).